# Arguments to tensorflow session.run() - do you pass operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following this [tutorial for tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/mnist/beginners):

I'm trying to understand the arguments to `tf.session.run()`. I understand that you have to run operations in a graph in a session.

Is `train_step` passed in because it encapsulates all the operations of the network in this particular example? I'm trying to understand why I don't need to pass any other variables to the session like `cross_entropy`.

```python
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Here is the full code:

```python
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))

b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(10):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a TensorFlow Session `tf.Session`, you want to run (or execute) the optimizer operation (in this case it is `train_step`). The optimizer minimizes your loss function (in this case `cross_entropy`), which is evaluated or computed using the model hypothesis `y`.

In the cascade approach, the `cross_entropy` loss function minimizes the error made when computing `y`, so it finds the best values of the weights `W` that when combined with `x` accurately approximates `y`.

So using a TensorFlow Session object `tf.Session` as `sess` we run the optimizer `train_step`, which then evaluates the entire Computational Graph.

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Because the cascade approach ultimately calls `cross_entropy` which makes use of the placeholders `x` and `y`, you have to use the `feed_dict` to pass data to those placeholders.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, Tensorflow is used to build a graph of operations. Your `train_step` operation (i.e. "minimize by gradient descent") is connected/depends on the result of `cross_entropy`. `cross_entropy` itself relies on the results of `y` (softmax operation) and `y_` (data assignment); etc.

When you are calling `sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})`, you are basically asking Tensorflow "*run all the operations leading to `train_step`, and return its result (with `x = batch_xs` and `y = batch_ys` for input)*". So yes, Tensorflow will itself go through your graph backward to figure out the operation/input dependencies for `train_step`, then execute all these operations forward, to return what you asked.